# R: For loop only works when manually executed

Tags: r, loops

so I have a dataframe with four number colums A,B,C and D

I now wrote a for-loop to change values row by row when certain conditions are met.

but nothing happens! If I manually set k=1, k=2, k=3 and run the two if functions in the loop manually it works! This seems like a bug to me?

```
for (k in nrow(list)) {

if(list$A[k]>list$C[k]) {list$C[k]=list$A[k]}
  
if(list$B[k]<list$D[k]) {list$D[k]=list$B[k]}

}

list
```

Example:

```
A          B           C          D
195679832  197768053   195000001  197500000
195679832  197768053   197500001  200000000
227573015  228592110   227500001  230000000
64199445   65230121    65000001   67500000
```

should become

```
A          B           C           D
195679832  197768053   195679832  197500000
195679832  197768053   197500001  197768053
227573015  228592110   227573015  228592110
64199445   65230121    64199445   65000000
64199445   65230121    65000001   65230121
```

again: when I manually increase k and run the content of the loop one by one it works just fine, but if i run the loop as a whole it wont execute the if clauses anymore. It gives no error message aswell.

Comment: It should be `for (k in seq_len(nrow(list)))`. Assume that your `list` is indeed a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgott the `1:` before `nrow(list)`. `k` was only receiving 4, not 1:4.

```
for (k in 1:nrow(list)) {

if(list$A[k]>list$C[k]) {list$C[k]=list$A[k]}
  
if(list$B[k]<list$D[k]) {list$D[k]=list$B[k]}

}

list
```